# passing pointer to recursive function which initially passed from main - cast to pointer from integer of different size -- C

Tags: c

I am getting pointer in recursive function as parameter which is allocated with memory using `malloc`in main. But the way I tried multiple times giving me error the last error was `cast to pointer from integer of different`  at like.

Question basically in below line I am trying to cast ptr value to pointer hoping that this will give me the pointer (so address which pointed to `*ptr` value).

```
    11 |     populate(arr,--n,(int *)*ptr);
```

the above line is in populate recursive function
this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void populate(int *arr,int n,int *ptr)
{
    if(n==0)
        return;
     --n;
     *ptr=*ptr+n;
     *ptr=(int)arr[n-1];
    populate(arr,--n,&*ptr);
}

int main() {
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr=(int *) malloc(sizeof (int)*5);
    populate(arr,5,ptr);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr+1);
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is just allocated 5 `int` sized memory and assign it to `ptr` and now the point of `populate` recursive function is so I can assign values of elements from `arr` array to `ptr` so ptr can be used to assess same number vales which also exist in `arr` arry so in main I can do `ptr+1` that should print 2 and so on

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to copy the items in `arr` to the same corresponding position in the memory allocated for `ptr` or are you trying to reverse the array data? I assume reverse because of `n - 1` and such but "ptr+1 should print 2" seems the opposite. This shows how reversing the array might look: https://ideone.com/kWP23X If you could clarify what you're actually hoping the data `ptr` points to should look like it would help.

Comment: `&*ptr` hmmm... what do you expect this to do?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying to do. It sounds like you just want to copy `arr` into memory pointed to by `ptr` !? But that's just a `memcpy` and doesn't require a recursive function.

Comment: @4386427 `*ptr` does it points to value whose address can be retrieved using `&` as in `&*ptr`?

Comment: @user786 Try this: `printf("ptr is %p\n", (void*)&*ptr);
     printf("ptr is %p\n", (void*)ptr);`

Comment: `memcpy(ptr, arr, sizeof arr);`  instead of `populate` and you are done.

Comment: OT: `printf("%d\n",*ptr+1);` is most likely not doing what you seem to expect...

Comment: @4386427 `printf("%d\n",*ptr+1); is most likely not doing what you seem to expect` yes I guess I thought that since I accessed the `ptr` memory location by using de-reference operator `*` once in populate function then I must use `*` with *ptr to able to read the value again in main then able to get the value again I supposed that I need to use de-reference operator like `*` in `*ptr+x`

Comment: @user786 When reading a value using `ptr` then `*ptr` is the same as `ptr[0]` (i.e. first array element)  and `*ptr + 1` is the same as `ptr[0] + 1` I think you want `*(ptr+1)` which is the same as `ptr[1]` (i.e. second array element)

Comment: @4386427 `When reading a value using ptr then *ptr is the same as ptr[0] and *ptr + 1 is the same as ptr[0] + 1 I think you want *(ptr+1) which is the same as ptr[1]` now it started to make sense. I think I knew it kind of forgot. thanks

Comment: @user786 It's still unclear to me what you are trying. Do you want 1) the memory pointed to by `ptr` to be a **copy** of `arr` or do you want 2) `ptr` to point to an **array of pointers** where the pointers are pointing to the elements of `arr`. These are two very deifferent things.

Comment: @4386427 I wanted ur 1st point in last comment. Not the second. But love to see it i think i would need array to pointer to int. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

> `ptr` can be used to assess same number vales which also exist in `arr`

If you want to access elements in `arr` by `ptr`, the type of `ptr` should be `int**`, which is an 'array of pointers of int', rather than `int*`, which is an 'array of ints'.

```c
populate(arr,--n,(int *)*ptr);
```

The error given by compilers is necessary. Since your `ptr` on L11 is originally an `int*`, applying the dereferencing operator * will return an `int`. Since you can not guarantee that your size of ints is equal to `void*`, converting an int to `int*` will lead to an error.

If you just want to copy an array, a plain `memcpy()` or even normal `for` loop will do. No need to write recursive funs.
As @4386427 has said above, `memcpy(ptr, arr, sizeof(arr));` will do.

Comment: `If you want to access elements in arr by ptr, the type of ptr should be int**, which is an 'array of pointers of int', rather than int*, which is an 'array of ints'.` No I dont want this. what I want is only get the values from arr not actual arr elements. otherwise which u mentioned make sense

Comment: `The error given by compilers is necessary. Since your ptr on L11 is originally an int*, applying the dereferencing operator * will return an int. Since you can not guarantee that your size of ints is equal to void*, converting an int to int* will lead to an error.` u need to point to my code.

Comment: @user786 What do you mean by 'get the values but not actual elements'? By the way, I have quoted your code.

Comment: Please take a look at the last paragraph of my answer. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Actually initially I was just trying to just get the 1 2 3 4 5 values and assign it to memory pointed to by ptr. But as u said use array ot pointer to int. But my system does not allow passing array of variable length so I assumed `**ptr` cant be passed and had as parameter signature. Just please show me how to pass `**ptr` to populate function.  I want to use `**ptr` in parameter if I use array of pointers of int.

Comment: @user786 So what is your env exactly? `int**` is essentially a pointer, so it should not be a problem to use it. Also, had I misunderstood your original purpose, you may just go ahead with `memcpy()` to implement your own idea.

Comment: can u please give me an example code to see how to pass `**ptr` from main and function signature and how its memory location is used in called function?